Bash Script to backup Chrome Extensions in MacOS?
Some Chrome Extensions use custom settings, is it possible to write bash script to somehow get extension settings as files and store on backup disk?
I'm interested in following extensions "uBlock Origin", "uBlacklist", "Channel Blocker".

What have you tried already, where are you stuck?

Having said that: Chrome stores all local data in ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome, backing up this directory should be enough.
